# How can I use Protocol Buffers for structuring a third party serial Communication Protocol?

Tags: protocol-buffers, decoding, serial-communication

I am working on an ECG module, which is giving out data in bytes. There's a protocol document about it explaining like how to structure the packets, that are coming out of the module.
**I want to decode that data.**
I am confused whether protocol buffers will help in this or not. Any other methods that would be helpful in this decoding and writing that protocol in Python ?

Comment: Protocol buffer includes its own serialization format. It looks like you want to implement your custom format, which isn't really supported. Of course, there's always a remote chance that your protocol is already [compatible](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) with protobuf, but that's more of a longshot.

Answer (score 1):

Protocol buffers only works with its own [encoding format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

For decoding a manufacturer-specific custom binary format, I would suggest Python's built-in [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. Here is a [basic tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struct-module-in-python) which is easy get started with.

If the manufacturer-specific format is text based instead, you can either use basic string manipulation to split it into tokens, or one of the [parsing libraries for Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing).